# How to create html list from a json file (handlebars)

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I have an empty todo list:

```
<ul class="list">

</ul>
```

I want to create a li inside that list for each json title I have in the following json data:

```
[{"id":2,"title":"Mandar cartas a impresión","description":"","status":false,"priority":1,"created_at":"2015-12-07T13:09:55.552Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T13:09:55.552Z","project_id":1},{"id":3,"title":"CIF Intracomunitario","description":"","status":false,"priority":1,"created_at":"2015-12-07T13:10:05.736Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T13:10:05.736Z","project_id":1},{"id":4,"title":"Uniformes Chef a Porter","description":"","status":false,"priority":1,"created_at":"2015-12-07T13:10:16.170Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T13:10:16.170Z","project_id":1},{"id":5,"title":"Personal","description":"","status":false,"priority":1,"created_at":"2015-12-07T13:10:31.569Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T13:10:31.569Z","project_id":1},{"id":1,"title":"Mandar contrato pleni","description":"","status":false,"priority":1,"created_at":"2015-12-07T13:09:36.747Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T13:13:12.068Z","project_id":1},{"id":17,"title":"Comprar TPV","description":"","status":false,"priority":null,"created_at":"2015-12-08T00:18:40.753Z","updated_at":"2015-12-08T00:18:40.753Z","project_id":1},{"id":18,"title":"Vajillas Zara Home","description":"","status":false,"priority":null,"created_at":"2015-12-08T00:18:54.580Z","updated_at":"2015-12-08T00:18:54.580Z","project_id":1},{"id":19,"title":"Tpv","description":"","status":false,"priority":null,"created_at":"2015-12-08T00:33:17.393Z","updated_at":"2015-12-08T00:33:17.393Z","project_id":1},{"id":21,"title":"Wifi - Contratar","description":"","status":false,"priority":null,"created_at":"2015-12-08T15:33:24.639Z","updated_at":"2015-12-08T15:33:24.639Z","project_id":1},{"id":22,"title":"Cuenta Definitiva Santander","description":"","status":false,"priority":null,"created_at":"2015-12-08T15:33:50.255Z","updated_at":"2015-12-08T15:33:50.255Z","project_id":1},{"id":23,"title":"Pagarés Kider","description":"","status":false,"priority":null,"created_at":"2015-12-08T15:34:08.162Z","updated_at":"2015-12-08T15:34:08.162Z","project_id":1}]
```

So, I have the following javascript which uses handlebars for templating:

```
 <script>    
    jQuery.getJSON("http://myurl/tasks.json", function(data){  
    var source   = $("#tasks-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
      $.each(data) function() {
         var context = data;
         var show    = template(context);
        $(".list").html(show);
      });
    });         
    </script>
```

My handlebars template:

```
  <script id="tasks-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li>
        <div>{{title}}</div>
    </li>
  </script>
```

It wont create a li in my html for each title in the json.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate for each object of the array received in the JSON, you have to use **this** instead of **data** to access to the object.
**data** is the whole array and **this** is the current object where you want to retrieve the title property:

```
$.each(data, function() {
     var context = this;
     var show    = template(context);
    $(".list").append(show);
  });
```

And also change the **html** method for **append** for don't overwrite the content.

Regards